# How to get number of rows accessed in each table of a query sql Oracle DB

Tags: sql, database, oracle, sql-execution-plan, explain

I have to get number of rows accessed in each table in sql query - oracle db. For example:

```
select *
from a inner join b on  a.t = b.t
where a.x in (1,2,3)

result expect:
table a: 5 rows
table b: 10 rows
```

I used

```
EXPLAIN PLAN FOR ...
```

then

```
SELECT PLAN_TABLE_OUTPUT
FROM TABLE(DBMS_XPLAN.DISPLAY);
```

But number of rows seem not exactly. Result is explain plan. How can i solve it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Looks like statistics aren't up to date.

Collect statistics for both tables, and then run explain plan again. How? Like this:

```
SQL> begin
  2    dbms_stats.gather_table_stats('SCOTT', 'EMP');
  3  end;
  4  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

Comment: Explain shows E-rows, but the actual plan and rowcounts may be different.

Answer (score 0):

I did it. To find out row accessed in explain plain. I do this

EXPLAIN PLAN FOR
select ...
from ...
where ...

SQL content store in  V$SQL. And result explain plain stored in  V$SQL_PLAN

```
SELECT SQL_ID, OPERATION, OPTIONS, OBJECT_NAME, OBJECT_TYPE, CARDINALITY
FROM V$SQL_PLAN
```

You can display it

```
SELECT *
FROM TABLE(DBMS_XPLAN.DISPLAY());
```

To find out rows accessed in execution plan. I do this

```
-- ALTER SESSION SET STATISTICS_LEVEL = ALL;
SELECT /*+ gather_plan_statistics TEST_PLAN*/ *
from ...
where ...
```

Result explain plain stored in  V$SQL_PLAN_STATISTICS_ALL

```
SELECT SQL_ID, OPERATION, OPTIONS, OBJECT_NAME, OBJECT_TYPE, CARDINALITY, LAST_OUTPUT_ROWS
FROM V$SQL_PLAN_STATISTICS_ALL
```

You can display it

```
SELECT *
FROM TABLE(DBMS_XPLAN.DISPLAY_CURSOR('sqlid',0,'ALLSTATS LAST'));
```

Addtional, you can view it in

```
SELECT *
FROM SYS.DBA_HIST_SQLTEXT

SELECT SQL_ID, OPERATION, OPTIONS, OBJECT_NAME, OBJECT_TYPE, CARDINALITY
FROM SYS.DBA_HIST_SQL_PLAN

SELECT SQL_ID, OPERATION, OPTIONS, OBJECT_NAME, OBJECT_TYPE, CARDINALITY, LAST_OUTPUT_ROWS
FROM SYS.DBA_SQLSET_PLANS;
```